# Comparing Strings in Bash with Logical Or

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue getting a a simple `y/n` question to work. Consider the following code:

```
 echo "Hi there"
 read ans
 if [[ $ans != "y" || $ans != "Y" || $ans != "YES" || $ans != "yes" ]]; then
      echo "Foo"
      exit 0
 fi
```

I've looked at – I would argue – some of the more informative answers on StackOverflow for advice: [Simple logical operators in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash)

I've tried all different types of variations such as:

```
if [[ ($ans != "y" || $ans != "Y" || $ans != "YES" || $ans != "yes") ]]; then
    echo "Foo"
    exit 0
fi

if [[ ($ans != "y*" || $ans != "Y*" || $ans != "YES*" || $ans != "yes*") ]]; then
    echo "Foo"
    exit 0
fi

if [[ ($ans != "y") || ($ans != "Y") || ($ans != "YES") || ($ans != "yes") ]]; then
    echo "Foo"
    exit 0
fi
```

Regardless of why I type in any of these cases, it automatically fails and I'm not sure why. If anyone has a better way to handle y/n answers then please let me know! Ideally I would like to use pattern matching (like I might do with Perl) but I'm not entirely sure the best way/most efficient way to accomplish a simple `y/n` question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`. As it stands you're saying if it's not equal to *any* of those possibilities, then execute the "then" block. You mean to say if it's not equal to *all* of them, then execute the "then" block. That requires `&&`.

Comment: Face palm... It must be something between too late or too early. I'll make this as the answer when SO allows me to

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
echo "Hi there"
read ans
case "$ans" in
    y|Y|YES|yes)
        ;;

    *)
      echo "Foo"
      exit 0
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Good but I only need to address a single case.

Answer (score 2):

The logic needs to be adjusted:

```
echo "Hi there"
read ans
if ! [[ "$ans" == "y" || "$ans" == "Y" || "$ans" == "YES" || "$ans" == "yes" ]]; then
     echo "Foo"  # User answered no
     exit 0
fi
```

The will echo "Foo" only if the answer was *not* one of "y", "Y" or "YES".  By contrast, consider the original logic:

```
[[ $ans != "y" || $ans != "Y" || $ans != "YES" || $ans != "yes" ]]
```

At least one of these tests will be true regardless of what the user's answer is.

#### Using the `case` statement

You might consider using the `case` statement to analyze the user's answer:

```
read -p "Hi there: " ans
case "$ans" in
    [yY]*) ;;
    [nN]*) echo "Foo" ; exit 0 ;;
    *) echo "You were supposed to answer yes or no" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `read ans`, not `read $ans`.

Comment: My bad, it's correct in my script but not on here. I'll change that