# "syntax near unexpected token `{cd'" defining shell function

Tags: linux, bash

Following advices I got from my previous post,I wrote a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

mycd() 
{cd /home/milenko/data;}

mycd

./p2
```

p2 is executable

But

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ bash a1.sh
a1.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `{cd'
a1.sh: line 4: `{cd /home/milenko/data;}'
```

Why?

Comment: Spaces are relevant, see the example in Charles' comment on your last question.

Comment: `{ cd /home/milenko/data; }`

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ok,spaces are relevant but what empty space mean?

Comment: An empty space separates two words. The first word in a command is syntax that determines what that command *is*. You can't run `{cd` and expect it to be identical to `cd` any more than you can run `acd` and expect it to do the same as `cd`.

Comment: `{` has different meaning in `bash` depending on whether it has a space after it.

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out issues like this.

Comment: It would be perfectly legal (but a bad idea) to have a command named `{cd`.

Comment: See [Simple logical operators in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash/6270803#6270803)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell syntax (not just bash, but in POSIX sh) is built around units called "words". `{` only has its syntactic meaning when parsed as its own word -- meaning it needs to be surrounded by whitespace (a category which includes newlines).

The conventional way to write this would be:

```
mycd() {
  cd /home/milenko/data
}
```

...or, if you wanted to minimize newlines:

```
mycd() { cd /home/milenko/data; }
```

You *could* remove the space between the final `;` and closing `}` (since `;`, when found outside quotes and not escaped, ends any word which was preceding it), but this would be considered ugly:

```
mycd() { cd /home/milenko/data;} # leaving out the last space is legal, but please don't.
```