# Why conditional exit on error is executed without any error in this example code

Tags: bash

I am dealing with weird thing in my bash script and I can't understand what is happening here:

```
cd ~ && printf "CWD is $(echo $(pwd))\n" || printf "Critical err.\n" && exit 1;
printf "This should be printed, but it won't be.\n";
```

Bash 4.4.20.

Comment: `exit 1` you are getting out of shell. remove this part

Comment: But it should be executed only if the first part of pipe fails since there is "||".

Comment: You need to use bracket then try `(cd ~ && printf "CWD is $(echo $(pwd))\n") || (printf "Critical err.\n" && exit 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
(cd ~ && printf "CWD is $(echo $(pwd))\n") || (printf "Critical err.\n" && exit 1)
```

[Check this thread for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash)

`||` and `&&` operands inside if condition (i.e. between round parentheses) are logical operands (or/and)